# Aggregate/Annotate issue with OuterRef not working with non-FK relationship in Django? Is FK required?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I've got an issue with a couple models from different 'shared apps' that I have. I can't FK them together, because these apps exist in multiple projects (some without each other) so it would break other projects.

This is an unmanaged model from `appA` - which uses a *different database* which we will call `databaseA` for this example; in a perfect world 'location_id' would be the FK but as I've described above, it cannot be.

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="ID", primary_key=True)
    location_id = models.IntegerField(db_column="locationID")
    grade = models.CharField(db_column="grade", max_length=10)
    student_count = models.IntegerField(db_column="studentCount")
 
    class Meta(object):
        managed = False
        db_table = "mytable_Enrollments"
```

This is a managed model from `appB` which uses `databaseB` (which is the primary database used by the rest of the apps in this project); the 'pk' or 'id' of this model is what is listed in the `Enrollment` model under `location_id`

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    alternate_name = models.IntegerField()
```

If I want to get `Enrollment` objects for a `Location`, I have to explicitly put a number in for the id like so:

```
location = Location.objects.get(id=1)
enrollments = Enrollment.objects.filter(location_id = location.id)
```

But I'm trying to annotate the 'total_student_count' onto the `Location` model like so:

```
enrollments = (
    Enrollment.objects.filter(location_id=OuterRef("pk"))
    .order_by()
    .values("location_id")
)
total_enrollments = enrollments.annotate(
    total_student_count=Sum("student_count")
).values("total_student_count")
locations = (
    Location.objects.all()
    .order_by()
    .annotate(
        total_enrollments=Subquery(total_enrollments),
    )
)
```

I did this similar to [examples from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/).

However this just returns `total_enrollments: None` in the Queryset.

If I replace `OuterRef("pk")` with an integer like 1 or 2 - the `enrollments` variable gives me back what I would expect. But using the `OuterRef` seems to break - and I'm not sure why.

Does it *need* to be a FK? From everything I've found online, it doesn't need to be. But I can't seem to find a way to make this work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The `Location` table is in one DB and `Enrollment` in another. When you write a subquery over there you basically ask for Django to make a cross database join which it doesn't support. You simply need to make separate queries and do the joining in Python.

Comment: I'm giving you an upvote because, this is the answer I dreaded to hear (that it wasn't possible). But I found a little nugget in the docs now that show it doesn't support that sort of multi-database situation. Real bummer, because it's a huge performance hit for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like following query

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F, Window

results = Enrollment.objects.filter(
    location_id__in=[location_ids]
).values(
    'location_id'
).distinct().annotate(
    total_student_count=Window(
        expression=Sum("student_count"), partition_by=[F("location_id")],
    )
).order_by('total_student_count')
```

This will filter the Enrollements based on provided location ids and will give total enrollements based on each location id

Comment: This almost does what I am looking for, but is there a way to annotate the `total_student_count` onto the `Location` model?

Comment: While this doesn't exactly answer the question - it at least gets me the information in a useable way so that I can do further joining in Python. Thank you.